# Simple postgres queries very slow

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres DB with a single table (reddit_comments) that contains all the reddit comments since 2007. There are only 10 columns in the table but I am only trying to query off of subreddit which is a text field. I have built a btree index for the subreddit.

Notes about the table:

1) About 1.5-2 billion rows.

2) There are no more insertions or deletions from the table. It is static.

3) There are 2 more indexes (author and month)

About hardware:

1) Intel 8 core processor

2) 128 GB of ram

3) Stored on a 7200 SATA drive

When I run the following query:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) select * from reddit_comments WHERE 
subreddit = 'boston' LIMIT 20000;
```

The query takes a significant amount of time and I get the following output:

```
Limit  (cost=0.70..80375.57 rows=20000 width=320) (actual 
time=32.421..52218.645 rows=20000 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=344 read=19532
   I/O Timings: read=52051.619
   ->  Index Scan using subr_idx on reddit_comments  
(cost=0.70..1487554.68 rows=370154 width=320) (actual 
time=32.419..52202.785 rows=20000 loops=1)
     Index Cond: (subreddit = 'boston'::text)
     Buffers: shared hit=344 read=19532
     I/O Timings: read=52051.619
 Planning time: 0.184 ms
 Execution time: 52228.975 ms
```

If I were to not set a limit = 20000 it takes hours to run (for about 600,000 results)

I have tried to implement many of the suggestions from here:

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions

but nothing seems to be speeding up the process. Is there something I am missing that would increase performance or is it just going to be slow to query this database whenever I need to get more data?

Comment: very curious to know where you got this dataset.

Comment: All your time is spent on read(); you probably have too few bufferspace, (this query could be served from memory only...) Or maybe your I/O throughput is very low.

Comment: Note:a similar query runs here in 6 seconds, on a (well-tuned) Postgres installation on a Raspberry Pi-2, which only has 10MB/s I/O bandwidth (over USB)

Comment: `There are only 10 columns in the table but I am only trying to query off of subreddit ...` *Why* a single table? Why not squeeze out the *low cardinality* {subreddit,user_it, ...} columns into separate tables, and refer to them via FKs ? Note: your rowwidth=320 is rather large, too.

Comment: Unless your I/O is saturated (is it?), PostgreSQL v10 with support for parallel index scans might help.

Comment: @wildplasser I am not great with psql and I coudln't think of a reason to include subreddit and user ID as their own table with a foriegn key when they would be the only column in the table (table Users: column userID and foriegn key). Also, is your dataset a similar reddit dataset (3 Terabytes of data) and if so how have you tuned your dataset to query in 6 seconds AND fit it on a rasberry pi?

Comment: No, this example dataset is only 1.8M rows, but in order to fetch a sample of 20K rows it still has to perform ~16K index-fetches, (which IMO is comparable to your query) And: yes, normalisation helps to reduce your memory-footprint.(and to avoid *fat* indexes)

Answer (score 0):

The data you want is spread all over the disk so it takes a lot of time to read it. If you're gonna operate mainly on subreddits you can execute:

```
CLUSTER reddit_comments USING subr_idx
```

This will reorder the data in the table so that the query will have to read a lot fewer pages when you run the query in your question. It may take longer to run queries based on other filter terms though, will lock the table exclusively and will take a lot of time ([ref](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-cluster.html)).